# how can i get ina219 sensor data with raspbery pi

Tags: c++, c, raspberry-pi3, sensors

I want some ask you guys a questions.

I'm trying to get data from current sensor 'ina219' with raspberry pi. 
I tried to get data with c++ but the data is different when i tried with python module

this data is what is tried and the following is data from python script

```
value:6912
value:10496
value:6912
value:6912
value:6912
value:10496
value:6912
value:3584
value:3584
value:-3329
value:0
value:14080
value:6912
value:6912
value:6912
value:3584
value:14080
value:14080
value:0
value:0
value:0
value:3584
value:3584
value:3584
value:6912
value:10496
value:10496
value:10496
value:10496
```

```
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.598 mA
bus current:-0.598 mA
bus current:-0.598 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.598 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.598 mA
bus current:-0.598 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.598 mA
bus current:-0.598 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.695 mA
bus current:-0.598 mA
```

I can't imagine what is the problem. Does anyone who success with getting sensor data with raspberry pi as C++? if there exist, please help me...
the following code is c++ code for current sensor

```
uint16_t cal, config;
float r_shunt,current_lsb,power_lsb;


void configure(int fd);
void calibrate(int fd,float shunt_val, float v_shunt_max, float v_bux_max, float i_max_expected);

int main(){
    int fd;
    int16_t result;
    unsigned char buffer[100];

    fd = wiringPiI2CSetup(0x40);

    configure(fd);
    calibrate(fd, 0.1 , 0.2 , 32, 2);


    while(1){
        result = wiringPiI2CReadReg16(fd, 0x04);//0x02);

        if(result == -1)
            cout<<"Error. Error is:"<<errno<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"value:"<<result<<endl;//*current_lsb<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
void configure(int fd){
    config = 0;
    //config |= (RANGE_32V<<BRNG | GAIN_8_320MV<<PG0 | ADC_12BIT << BADC1 | ADC_12BIT << SADC1 | CONT_SH_BUS);
    config |= (1<<13 | 3<<11 | 3<<7 | 3 << 3 | 7);
    int result = wiringPiI2CWriteReg16(fd, 0x00,config);
    if(result == -1)
        cout<<"Error, is :"<<errno<<endl;
}

void calibrate(int fd,float shunt_val, float v_shunt_max, float v_bux_max, float i_max_expected){
    uint16_t digits;
    float min_lsb,swap;

    r_shunt = shunt_val;
    min_lsb = i_max_expected / 32767;

    current_lsb = min_lsb;
    digits = 0;

    while(current_lsb > 0.0){
        if((uint16_t)current_lsb /1){
            current_lsb = (uint16_t) current_lsb +1;
            current_lsb /= pow(10,digits);
            break;
        }else{
            digits++;
            current_lsb *= 10.0;
        }
    };

    swap = (0.04096)/(current_lsb*r_shunt);
    cal = (uint16_t)swap;
    power_lsb = current_lsb *20;
    int result = wiringPiI2CWriteReg16(fd, 0x05,cal);
    if(result == -1)
        cout<<"Error, is:"<<errno<<endl;

}
```

Comment: HI, Did you solve this situation. I'm having same problem

Comment: No... sorry for late. I was in a hurry at that time. so I just used library of python instead of C++.

Comment: Too bad :( I'm having same problem :D

Answer (score 0):

I see several possible differences :

1. Configuration is different from your python script :

   - Run your python script
   - Dump the configuration register (address 0x00) with `wiringPiI2CReadReg16(fd,0x00)` before and after calling `configure(fd);` to identify any differences
2. Calibration is not done exactly the same way :

   - Maybe it's not required to calibrate the INA every-time you start your program. If you're goal is to identify why the python script result is different, then do the calibration once and test both script. ( By removing the calibration from your CPP program and running in this order the python script then the CPP program for instance).
3. The sampling rate is different (time between two data request) :

   - You are calling `result = wiringPiI2CReadReg16(fd, 0x04);` in a while(1) continuously without any delay. Is it done the same way in the python script ?
   - Identify the sensor behavior when you request data continuously ( does it repeat the same measurement ? ). You should probably consider requesting data at a lower rate.
   - If the sampling rate is different from the python script it's normal to have different measurement as the signal is maybe noisy.